# Rails4 Nested Form not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a triple nested form where a Form has many questions and questions have many answers. I have each form rendering on the show page with the form title and the form questions and input fields to create new answers associated with the asked question. The association is linking up nicely, however I cant seem to get the answers to insert into the db. I feel like it is something real easy but I cant seem to figure it out.

-Form-

```
<%= simple_form_for @form do |f|  %>
  <%= f.error_notification  %>
  <h1><%= @form.name  %></h1>
  <div class="fields">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :form_questions do |q| %>
      <%= label_tag q.index+1 %>
      <%= q.simple_fields_for :form_answers, q.object.form_answers.build do |a|  %>
        <%= a.input :answer, label: false %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="fields">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => "button", value: 'Submit'  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

-Form Controller-

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @form = Form.new
      @form.form_questions.form_answers.build
    end

    def create
      @form = Form.new(form_params)
    end

    def index
      @forms = Form.includes(:form_questions).all
    end

    def show
      @form = Form.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
      @form = Form.find(params[:id])
    end


    def form_params
      params.require(:form).permit(:id, :name, form_questions_attributes: [:title, form_answers_attributes: [:answer]])
    end

  end
```

-Form Answer Controller (although if the associations are correct I feel like I should be able to handle everything in the forms controller)

```
class FormAnswersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @form_answer = FormAnswer.new
  end

  def create
    @form_answer = FormAnswer.new(form_answer_params)
    if @form_answer.save
      RequestMailer.request_submit(@form).deliver
    else
      format.html {render action: 'new'}
    end
  end

  def form_answers_params
    params.require(:form_answer).permit(:form_id, :form_question_id, :id, :answer)
  end

end
```

-Server Logs-

```
Started PATCH "/forms/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-05 13:31:44 -0400
Processing by FormsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CcaCGjdoYPH2Boi1prIFhG+h5YuPHQvAxMp1dcKvWr8=", "form"=>{"form_questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"form_answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"answer"=>"hey"}}, "id"=>"50"}, "1"=>{"form_answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"answer"=>"ya"}}, "id"=>"51"}, "2"=>{"form_answers_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"answer"=>"go"}}, "id"=>"52"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"12"}
  Rendered forms/update.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 11.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Try `@form.form_questions.build` instead of `@form.form_questions.form_answers.build`.Not sure tough.

Comment: Yeah, that didnt do anything. The thing is because it is nested, I only want to create new records for form_answer, however I dont want to create new records for forms or form questions, those are only added by an admin through the back end. Its been tricky to try and get a new record inserted through the update action...

Comment: @blakeyoder answer is very close to what I had posted so try it yourself. If you still couldn't then will post an answer later or may be someone else will

Comment: @blakeyoder Are you seeing any errors for "Unpermitted parameters:" in your log? Your parameters for `form_questions_attributes` includes an `id` but that is not specified in your strong parameters. For example, it should be `... form_questions_attributes: [:id, :title, form_answers_attributes: [:answer]]`. May or may not be the issue but is something I noticed.